# If I am implementing Oauth2 as an Identify Provider, do I really need to implement Authentication on top of it using something like OpenID

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

The big security issue always brought up when using OAuth2 seems to be centered around not technically being Authentication. However, if you are the owner of the identify provider and the resources being accessed, doesn't this accomplish authentication and thus make not necessary implementing a solution on like OpenID Connect on top?

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth there's only one token that is being passed around (an access token) which is opaque to the Client/RP. The access token represents a capability that is given by an end user but it doesn't say anything about that user: not who the user is nor whether and how the user authenticated (because as said the token contains no information whatsoever by spec).

Anything that you can come up with would lead to an extension of OAuth 2.0 by adding the information described above in the (or a different) token - thus make it no longer opaque to the RP - and/or define an endpoint where that information about the user can be obtained. But then this extension would be exactly what OpenID Connect has standardized so it would not make much sense to deviate from that.

Comment: Implementing OAuth2 with the ASP.net Identity System would work for this wouldn't it: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: doesn't look like it, but this will: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/28/owin-security-components-in-asp-net-openid-connect.aspx

Comment: Where the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider is overriding GrantResourceOwnerCredentials where you can add any and all identity information to the bearer token.